# C#/ADO.NET - Rows being skipped while using SetField in datatable?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable, ado.net

I have a console application that is ran daily to update my database.

Everyday, the application pulls all the Ticket data into a datatable.

In this particular case, I am trying to calculate whether each ticket in the database that has not been responded too, has passed the max response time allotted for that ticket (in hours). Ticket reported date vs Today's date.

If the response time has passed a value of 0(false) is set in the Response_met column, else 1(true).

When new tickets are added to the database, their Response_Met is originally NULL until this update is ran and calculates whether or not the response_time has passed or not.

This is the datatable before the udpate.

[image]

The highlighted cell is currently NULL. After the update, it should change to 0(false) because the Max_response_time is 1.00 HOUR, and the ticket was Reported in 2014, and does not have a response_time.

This is the datatable after the update, it hasent changed.

[image]

Their are several instances of this happening in the datatable, I am just showing the first instance here.

Can anyone tell where the issue is? Why are some rows being skipped and left NULL after the update? It works for the majority of rows, except a handful of them. Below is the update code I have written.

```
using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("SELECT INCIDENT_NO, Report_DT, MIN(theStart) as The_Start, RESPONSE_TIME, Response_met, max_response_time FROM Ticket_REPORT rr left JOIN TimeTracker ON Incident_NO=theTask where theStart is null and impact like '3%' or theStart is null and impact like '4%' GROUP BY INCIDENT_NO, Report_DT,RESPONSE_TIME,Response_met,MAX_RESPONSE_TIME", sqlConn))
            {
                var calc = new Calculation(holidays, new OpenHours("09:00;17:00"));//Calculates business hours
                SqlDataAdapter da2 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd2);
                dtResponse.Clear();
                da2.Fill(dtResponse);

                foreach (DataRow row in dtResponse.Rows)
                {
                    var reportDT = row.Field<string>(dtResponse.Columns[1]);
                     //Check if business hours have passed alloted response time
                    if (TimeSpan.FromMinutes(calc.getElapsedMinutes(DateTime.Parse(reportDT), DateTime.Now)).TotalHours > (double)row.Field<decimal>(dtResponse.Columns[5]))
                    {
                        row.SetField(dtResponse.Columns[4], 0);
                    }
                }
                da2.Dispose();
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should call `da2.Update(dtResponse)` to actually update the database, otherwise you're just changing the datarow rowstate

Comment: Updating the database isent really the issue, I am doing that elsewhere in the code. The issue is rows are being skipped and left null in my foreach loop

Comment: So whenever I update my database, nulls are being applied where, in this case, a 0 should be.

Comment: Can you start the sql profiler and see if the rows are actually updating correctly?

Comment: I dont have experience using that, Iv never heard of it. Is it simple?

Comment: Yes it's quite simple. Check out this [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21371/SQL-Server-Profiler-Step-by-Step). It's using an old version (Sql Server 2005) but it's almoste the same nowadays